# How to resolve date time and buffer/memory view objects error in python

Tags: python

I have python 2.6 installed. And the code in script also written in python 2.6. I am getting following error when i execute python script.

```
dbi.py:13: DeprecationWarning: dbi module is obsolete, code should now use native python datetime and buffer/memoryview objects
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning that is meant to direct developers away from using the `dbi-module` because, as the warning says it's obsolete.

The native objects in this case are [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and maybe [memoryview](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview-type). I don't think that's useful for you, unless you've developed that script. If so, port to a newer version.

Comment: cannot be ported to newer version as i have lots of scripts to do so.

Comment: Well maintaining those scripts will not be any easier in the future as the community moves towards python 3.